# Dynamic alerts with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this HTML form below (radio buttons) which is having 3 questions with answers A, B and C.

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Question 1:</legend>
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="first" />A</label> <br />
<label><input name="first" type="radio" value="2" />B</label> <br />
<label><input name="first" type="radio" value="3" />C</label> <br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Question 2:</legend>
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="second" />A</label> <br />
<label><input name="second" type="radio" value="2" />B</label> <br />
<label><input type="radio" value="3" name="second" />C</label> <br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Question 3:</legend>
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="third" />A</label> <br />
<label><input name="third" type="radio" value="2" />B</label> <br />
<label><input type="radio" value="3" name="third" />C</label> <br />
</fieldset>

<div id="display">Please answer all the questions</div>​
```

What I need here is a jQuery script to display 3 answers dynamically. The 3 answers should be like below:

1. Answer 1 (if 2 or more answers are A)
2. Answer 2 (if 2 or more answers are B)
3. Answer 3 (if 2 or more answers are C)

Nothing is displayed if the answers are A, B and C.

I'm not a jQuery pro but I just have the script (below) to check if the answers are completed or not. Can anyone help me with this?

```
$('input:radio').click(
function() {
    var q = $('fieldset').length;
    console.log('q: ' + q + '; checked: ' + $('input:radio:checked').length);
    if ($('input:radio:checked').length == q){
        $('#display').text('You\'ve completed all questions!');
    }
    else {
        $('#display').text('You\'ve not yet finished...');
    }
});​
```

Thanks in advance.
JSFiddle Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/BhanuChawla/KSd3M/

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly.

Comment: I've formatted the question above. All I want is one answer out of 3 possibilities.

Comment: OK, maybe a bit pedantic, but it'd be easier to see what's going on if the attributes (type, name, value) were all in the same order. Easier to edit in future, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have done complete bins for above issue. you can check demo link too.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp74

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Question 1:
  </legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="first" />
    A
  </label>

  <label>
    <input name="first" type="radio" value="2" />
    B
  </label>

  <label>
    <input name="first" type="radio" value="3" />
    C
  </label>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Question 2:
  </legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="second" />
    A
  </label>

  <label>
    <input name="second" type="radio" value="2" />
    B
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="second" />
    C
  </label>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Question 3:
  </legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="third" />
    A
  </label>

  <label>
    <input name="third" type="radio" value="2" />
    B
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="third" />
    C
  </label>
</fieldset>
<div id="display">
  Please answer all the questions
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {

    var answers = Array();
    $("input:radio").click(function() {
        var index = 0;
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            index = $(this).closest("fieldset").index();
            answers[index] = $(this).val().trim();
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
            if ($("input:radio[value=" + answers[i] + "]:checked").length > 1) {
                $("#display").text("Max Answers Selected:" + answers[i]);
                break;
            } else if ($("input:radio:checked").length >= 3) {
                $("#display").text("All have different Answers..!");
            }
        }

    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
label{
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  font-size:14px;
}

#display{
  margin-top:10px;
  border:1px solid #335599;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:14px;
  background:#a4a1df;
}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp74

Comment: That is really good. That is a complete solution to my query. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

```
var answers = {
    "1": "Answer 1",
    "2": "Answer 2",
    "3": "Answer 3"
};

$("input[type='radio']").on("click", function() {
    var vals = $("fieldset input:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        if (vals[i] == (vals[i + 1] || null)) {
            $("#display").text(answers[vals[i]]);
            break;
        }
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mLnWP/

Comment: Brilliant. Works as I wanted. Thanks :)

Comment: The jQuery is working fine on JSFiddle but not when put in an html file. See here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/47288696/Untitled-2.html 
Do you have any idea what's causing the jQuery to not work properly in an html document?

Comment: @BhanuChawla You have illegal symbol after `});` in the last line of JS. It causes the error. Remove the symbol and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Can we display images instead of text i.e., instead of Answer 1 or Answer 2 - can we display an image? The issue is that I can't store an image as a var because it just shows the link to the image instead of the image in the result.